# Compiler ignores my if statement in while(true)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

here's my code for sending messages every 3 seconds for 10 times.
but it ignores all of if statements in while(true)

```
double current;
double freq;
QueryPerformanceFrequency((LARGE_INTEGER*)&freq);
QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER*)&current);
float totalTime = 0.f;
float counter = 0.f;
while (true)
{
    double previous = current;
    QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER*)&current);
    double deltaTime = (current - previous) / freq;
    totalTime += deltaTime;
    counter += deltaTime;


    if (counter > 3.f)
    {
        cout << "msg Sent" << totalTime << "\n";
        counter = 0;
    }
    if (totalTime > 30.f)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

weird thing is that if I print out two of those values in the middle,
it works fine.

```
double current;
double freq;
QueryPerformanceFrequency((LARGE_INTEGER*)&freq);
QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER*)&current);
float totalTime = 0.f;
float counter = 0.f;
while (true)
{
    double previous = current;
    QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER*)&current);
    double deltaTime = (current - previous) / freq;
    totalTime += deltaTime;
    counter += deltaTime;

    cout << totalTime << "\n";
    cout << counter << "\n";

    if (counter > 3.f)
    {
        cout << "msg Sent" << totalTime << "\n";
        counter = 0;
    }
    if (totalTime > 30.f)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

I think it happened because of compiler optimization. if I'm right, is there any way to stop  compiler messing up my code?

```
LARGE_INTEGER current;
LARGE_INTEGER freq;
QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);
QueryPerformanceCounter(&current);

float totalTime = 0.f;
float counter = 0.f;
while (true)
{
    LARGE_INTEGER previous = current;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&current);

    double deltaTime = (current.QuadPart - previous.QuadPart) / static_cast<double>(freq.QuadPart);

    totalTime += deltaTime;
    counter += deltaTime;

    if (counter > 3.f)
    {
        cout << "msg Sent" << totalTime << "\n";
        counter = 0;
    }
    if (totalTime > 30.f)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

This time I followed c++ rule and the result is same. So it's not the trouble of casting. and it also works when i put two prints in the middle.

Comment: `QueryPerformanceFrequency` wants an integer, not a double.  The c-style cast you do causes undefined behavior.

Comment: does it have to do with ignoring if statements in the loop? my code works totally fine when i just put two print statement in the middle.

Comment: undefined behavior means anything can happen, including ignoring your if statements.

Comment: @HHKim That's what happens when you break the rules, the code has Undefined Behavior. It can result in very strange things like the code appearing to work sometimes and not working other times, or causing other parts of your program to act in inexplicable ways like an `if` always evaluating to `false` regardless of its condition.

Comment: Technically Undefined behaviour can result in anything, including time-travelling assassin robots from the future knocking on your door and asking for Sarah Connor.

Comment: Strange results like this are a very common consequence of undefined behavior. The extra prints in the middle change what's in the stack, and that changes how the previous undefined behavior manifests.

Comment: *"I think it happened because of compiler optimization. if I'm right, is there any way to stop compiler messing up my code?"* If your code breaks due to optimizations, then your code contains errors that the compiler can't account for.  This is a very common thing to happen to code with Undefined Behavior. The solution is to fix the error, the compiler is not allowed to optimize in a way that breaks correct code.

Comment: I tested your code, it executes the if of the break correctly. And the other too.

Comment: @CGi03: please read about undefined behavior before you post something about correctness in C++. This is an obscure thing you need to know if you program in C++. As many others said: anything can happen. It may even appear to succeed.

Comment: @CGi03 That's the trouble with undefined behavior, you might just get the results you expected.  The OP is violating the strict aliasing rules so there code is not valid.

Comment: you guys are saying undefined behavior but that's the reference of example about how to get deltaTime in game projects. and "AS YOU GUYS SAID" I tested my code without breaking any rules like changing all doubles into LARGE_INTEGER or casting using static_cast not c-style casting. have you guys ever tested my codes?

Comment: I uploaded new version. see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that the problem is due to `deltaTime` being significantly smaller than `3.f` and `30.f`.

Since, unless either `if` branch is taken, the loop body doesn't do anything except measure a clock, the time between iterations is likely to be very small. Initially, this won't be a problem and `deltaTime` will be correctly added to `counter` and `totalTime`. However, as these variables increase in size, they will eventually become so large that `deltaTime` will fall below the precision provided by `double`. When this happens, adding `deltaTime` will cease to increase these variables as the result will round out to exactly the original value.

This is made worse by using `float` to represent `counter` and `totalTime`, which is the floating point type with the lowest precision, meaning the problem will appear for at larger values of `deltaTime` than if a better floating point type was used.

By adding several `std::cout` the loop body may be slowed enough that `deltaTime` is always large enough to be meaningful relative to `counter` and `totalTime`.

Instead of counting time using imprecise floating point types, use integer types when possible to avoid this problem. Based on `freq` you can calculate how many ticks are equivalent to your `3.f` and `30.f` constants. You can then just count ticks and compare that count to the calculated limits.

Comment: cool! You are so right, it works like a charm when totalTime and counter changed into double instead of float. this problem happened after i changed my CPU yesterday, my PC is way faster than my previous one.  it quickly processes the queries so it has no time to get significant value for float. Thanks! it was confusing problem

Comment: @HHKim Beware that the change to `double` might fix the problem *for now* but the underlying bug still remains. The actual fix is to use integer arithmetic for this type of task.

Comment: A better solution might be to simply not use `QueryPerformanceFrequency()`/`QueryPerformanceCounter()` directly at all. The standard C++ library has a `<chrono>` library available since C++11, which has various clocks available for timing code. Consider re-writing this code to use that library instead.